# d3.js to remove two elements with matching attribute when clicked consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have two elements with identical href attributes. They are clicked, adding a class.
If, in addition, the href of the element clicked first is equal to the href of the element clicked second, they will be filtered out.

```
  removeBubble = function(d) {

    var currentId;
    currentId = idValue(d);

   d3.select(this).classed("clicked",true);    // on click add class
   if (d3.selectAll(".clicked").length === 2 && // 2 elements class clicked
          d3.select(this).prev.attr("href") ===  // href of 1st elem
          d3.select(this).next.attr("href"))     // href of 2nd elem
          {
         // filter here
          }
  };
```

**The task:**
1. check if the elements clicked have matching href

How can I achieve the .prev() and .next() - jQuery assessors - effect in d3.js ?

so far: Uncaught TypeError: a.target.className.indexOf is not a function

Comment: can you explain what you mean by 'the code is not correct'? What happens, and is there an error message?

Comment: those are jQuery assessors; they do not  work in the d3.js code ? Further my elements match on the href, they are not next to each other. I am trying to adapt the jQuery code to working d3.js. Not sure what to write to the console to test.

Comment: I'd say, start by creating a global variable. In your click handler, assign the clicked element to that global variable (if it isn't assigned) or check if the clicked element matches the relevant properties of the element assigned to the global variable. Once you've got that working, look into protecting the variable and the handler function in a closure so you don't have a global variable.

Comment: @Mousey Thank you both, Ethan and  Mousey for taking your time to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final working solution with comments:

```
removeBubble = function(d) {
  var currentId;
  currentId = idValue(d);

// when this clicked attach class

  var clicked = d3.select(this).classed("clicked",true);

 // ascribe href of elements with class clicked to variable

  var clicktext = d3.selectAll(".class1.clicked").attr("href");
  var clicklabel = d3.selectAll(".class2.clicked").attr("href");

// if no match remove class clicked and update
// else remove elements and update

   if ( clicklabel !== clicktext){
     console.log("it's not a match !");


     d3.selectAll(".clicked").classed("clicked",false);
     update();
     return d3.event.preventDefault();

 } else {  
    console.log("its a match !");


    data = data.filter(function(e) {
    return idValue(e) !== currentId;
    });
 }

 update();
 return d3.event.preventDefault();
};
```

The point is to remove the class that is used to identify the elements in the case when two elements with different href values are clicked consecutively: remove class, update = start fresh.